# Creating Events for hard disk read and write

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I am trying to write something that will fire an event anytime the hard disk reads data or writes data. I know this involves using System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter but I don't know this well enough to be able to do this on my own. Can someone point me in the right direction? Also, I'd like the event that fires to return which drive is being read or written to. Any help would be appreciated. This is C#, by the way.

Comment: IF you really want an event for EVERY disk-related R/W THEN you will need to implement a so-called filesystem-driver - which can't be implemented in .NET . If you could describe more clearly what you goal is exactly perhaps there is another approach to get the results you aim for...

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a sort of "Disk Light". Something that sits in the tray that flashes red whenever a write operation is going on in the hard drive and flashes green whenever a read operation is going on.

Comment: Is this more of a convenience kind of thing OR are you aiming at security (i.e. monitoring any disk-activitiy)?

Comment: A conveinience thing. A friend of mine used to use some kind of TSR for DOS back in the day and wants something for Windows, so I told her I'd see what I could do.

Comment: if it is for convenience there are tools out there that already do this - for example http://www.oo-software.com/en/products/oodriveled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following does not create events but you could use it together with a timer to display information in the tray (as per comments):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

private PerformanceCounter diskRead = new PerformanceCounter();
private PerformanceCounter diskWrite = new PerformanceCounter();

diskRead.CategoryName = "PhysicalDisk";
diskRead.CounterName = "Disk Reads/sec";
diskRead.InstanceName = "_Total";

diskWrite.CategoryName = "PhysicalDisk";
diskWrite.CounterName = "Disk Writes/sec";
diskWrite.InstanceName = "_Total";
```

`_Total` is for ALL disks... to get the specific instancenames of available disks use:

```
var cat = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory("PhysicalDisk");
var instNames = cat.GetInstanceNames();
```

you can then create a pair of `diskRead`/`diskWrite` for every instance you are interested in... for sample on how to use this in combination with a timer see [this](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.de/2012/01/performance-counters-in-net.html).

Comment: Will this get read/write info for CD drives too? I know I didn't specify it, but I'm just curious

Comment: @icemanind not sure (can't test that right now)... you can finde all available Categories by calling `PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories()`... you can find all instances by calling `GetInstanceNames()` on each found Category... HTH